# PowerApps IF OR Formula for Date < Today()+15

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

IF OR formula works until I add a date that checks to see if selected date occurs after 15 days from today.

```
// Works w/o date
If(Or( IsBlank(txtClientNameSignature), !IsNumeric(txtNumDocsToSign.Text) ), DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)
```

However, once I add a date formula, it does not correctly evaluate the date.

```
// Does NOT Work Due to Date Forumala
If(Or( IsBlank(txtClientNameSignature), !IsNumeric(txtNumDocsToSign.Text), dpkrDueDateSignature.SelectedDate < Today()+15 ), DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)
```

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error when you add the date comparison? If not, how does this new formula not work?

Comment: @carlosfigueira - Naturally I got it working shortly after posting.  Here is the solution:

If(Or( IsBlank(txtClientNameSignature), !IsNumeric(txtNumDocsToSign.Text), dpkrDueDateSignature.SelectedDate < DateAdd( Today(), 15, Days) ), DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)

Comment: Great. Can you post the solution as an answer, and accept it as the solution? This way if someone else has a similar issue, they will be able to see what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
If(Or( IsBlank(txtClientNameSignature), !IsNumeric(txtNumDocsToSign.Text), dpkrDueDateSignature.SelectedDate < DateAdd( Today(), 15, Days) ), DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)
```

DateAdd( Today(), 15, Days) is what I needed.